# Git is incorrectly ignoring files

Tags: git

I have a repo that has the following folders,

```
/test/
/input/
/misc/
/app/
```

I want to exclude all files other then the directories test, input and misc.
Ive added a file .git/info/exclude which contains

```
/*
!/test/*
!/input/*
!/misc/*
```

However when I perform a 'git add *' I get the following.,

```
[root@server folder]# git add *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
test
input
misc
app
```

Ive checked the ignore file via the command

```
[root@server folder]#  git config core.excludesfile
.git/info/exclude
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm assuming `/*` looks the same as `*`, since you can ignore a directory like `dir/` (suggesting the leading slash doesn't matter).

Comment: Try using `git check-ignore -v <file>` to see why Git is ignoring a particular file.

Comment: @Sam: The leading slash does matter:  `/foo/` means to ignore the directory named `foo` at the top of the working directory (or whichever directory contains the `.gitignore` file), while `foo/` means to ignore a directory named `foo` anywhere in the working directory.  See [`git help ignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for details.

Comment: Are you asking why Git is warning you about those ignored files, or are you asking why Git thinks those files are ignored?

Comment: Awesome, thanks @RichardHansen -- gotta love what you learn on SO (time to read some docs and update some `.gitignore`s).

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this entries on `.git/info/exclude` file:

```
/*
!test/
!input/
!misc/
```

Comment: whats the importance of the forward slash. wouldnt that relate to root.

Comment: You can set the forward slash in folders, like this:
`!/test/`  and the behaviour would be the same.
The important stuff is the slash on `/*`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Git are you using?  I am unable to reproduce the problem with Git v1.9.2.

The following script:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/repo /tmp/repo/foo /tmp/repo/bar
cd /tmp/repo
git init .
cat <<EOF >.git/info/exclude
/*
!/foo/
EOF
echo blah | tee foo/blah | tee bar/blah >blah
git add *
```

produces the following output:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
bar
blah
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Note that `foo` is not listed in the output.